# using pragma or any programmatic way of excluding a cpp/header file from a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction

I know there are other questions regarding that, and I also know that I can right click on the files that I want excluded, and select **Exclude from Project**. However. I'm wondering if there are any easy ways of achieving the same purpose programmatically. For example, in a VS project, to link with an external library, I can either add the library name in the project's settings under **Linker** options, or use "pragma comment(lib, library name in char*)". I'm wondering if this can be achieved similar to how I have described my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if 0

#endif
```

Seriously, though... no there's no pragma for that. Even Microsoft isn't quite that silly :P

You can #include a .cpp file to include it without it specifically being part of the project, but your only option to exclude a file is the way you described.

Comment: This would be the last resort of what I would like to do, as I don't want to wrap the body of the header and source file that I want excluded with similar macros.

Comment: Header files are not really part of the project, they're only compiled if they're #included. VS just lets you add them to the project as a convenience so you have easy access to open them.

If you're wanting to do what I think, and the header is included in other files, the only real option is to enclose both in similar macros like #ifndef _NO_FOO and then add _NO_FOO in your preprocessor directives when you want to exclude them